# search ranges and lists

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, wmic

```
psloggedon -l USERNAME
```

I wanted to use the above command to search the network for the username logged on locally. But this scans the entire network. I was wondering if there was any way to specify a range of computer system names, like "C6000 - C7000" or specify a list.txt to use?

And if that is not possible, I then wanted to try using a list.txt with the command:

```
wmic.exe /node:%computername% ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

If both are possible, would love to know how that works.

Answer (score 1):

A explained in [WMIC switches Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787035%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), you can use the `/NODE` like this :

```
/NODE:"TESTSERVER1","TESTSERVER2",@"C:\COMPUTERLIST.TXT"
```

Where `C:\COMPUTERLIST.TXT` is file containing a list of computers.

---

Edited :

You create the file `C:\COMPUTERLIST.TXT` you can perhaps extract it from your Active Directory :

```
C6000
C6001
C6002
....
C7000
```

Then you use :

```
wmic.exe /node:@"C:\COMPUTERLIST.TXT" ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

Comment: So how do I combine that with the rest of my command? I am confused by the "testserver1" thing since I want to use a .txt file

Comment: @Aaron, I edited my answer to give you a way you can call it. The sample I give show how to simultaneously give computers and a file with computers.